# What is the cheapest way to roundup() or ceil() to multiple of 1000?

Tags: solidity, compilation

What is the cheapest way to roundup() or ceil() to multiple of 1000?

For example if cheapest way to roundup is implemented in the ceil function:

```
function ceil(uint a, uint m) returns (uint) {
    //some cheap roundup to muliple function
}
```

then it is expected that:

- ceil(123456,1000) == 124000
- ceil(1,1000) == 1000
- ceil(0,1000) == 0
- ceil(123000,1000) == 123000

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
contract Ceil {
    function ceil(uint a, uint m) constant returns (uint ) {
        return ((a + m - 1) / m) * m;
    }

    // To measure gas
    function ceil1(uint a, uint m) returns (uint ) {
        return ((a + m - 1) / m) * m;
    }
}
```

And testing for the correct results:

```
> ceil.ceil(123456, 1000)
124000
> ceil.ceil(1,1000)
1000
> ceil.ceil(0,1000)
0
> ceil.ceil(123000,1000)
123000
```

To measure the gas, I've created `ceil1(...)` and sent a transaction:

```
> ceil.ceil1(123456, 1000, eth.accounts[0], {
   from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
   data: ceilCompiled.Ceil.code,
   gas: 1000000
});
"0xeac6bb84ba5a1703ee3a762cb392f1793adf550906b6112e441928c0ea288f53"
...
> debug.traceTransaction("0xeac6bb84ba5a1703ee3a762cb392f1793adf550906b6112e441928c0ea288f53")
{
  gas: 21990,
  returnValue: "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e460",
  structLogs: [{
```

The gas cost of this calculation is 21,990. This figure would include the default 21,000 gas for sending a regular transaction which gives an incremental gas cost of 990.

When plugging the code into the Online Solidity Compiler at https://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-latest.js, the following gas cost are estimated:

```
Creation: 69 + 43000
External:
  ceil(uint256,uint256): 275
  ceil1(uint256,uint256): 253
Internal:
```

So an estimate for the gas cost of `ceil1(...)` is between 253 and 990.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is the cheapest, but one of solutions I have managed to invent is this one:

```
function ceil(uint a, uint m) returns (uint r) {
    return (a + m - 1) / m * m;
}
```