# Solidity is installed but is not working within geth, on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, installation, ubuntu

Geth console outputs after `admin.setSolc("/usr/bin/solc")`:

```
eth.compile.solidity("")
I0601 15:31:56.663260 common/compiler/solidity.go:114] solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.3.3-0/RelWithDebInfo-Linux/g++/Interpreter
path: /usr/bin/solc
solc: empty source string
at web3.js:3119:20
at web3.js:6023:15
at web3.js:4995:36
at :1:1
```

and

```
eth.getCompilers()
[]
```

I am getting an empty array instead of `['Solidity']`.

Installed solidity through: `sudo apt-get install solc`

output for `which solc`: `/usr/bin/solc` (added this to PATH)

I have seen a similar [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4102/link-solc-with-geth-problem), but I am using the latest version (0.3.3) and still have the problem. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The empty `eth.getCompilers()` result is normal.

You can try the below:

```
> eth.getCompilers()
[]
> var ceilSource='contract Ceil { function ceil(uint a, uint m) constant returns (uint ) { return ((a + m - 1) / m) * m; }}'
undefined
> var ceilCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(ceilSource);
undefined
> ceilCompiled
{
  Ceil: {
    code: "0x606060405260348060106000396000f3606060405260e060020a60003504638587be6e8114601a575b005b602435600435810160001901819004026060908152602090f3",
    info: {
      abiDefinition: [{...}],
      compilerOptions: "--bin --abi --userdoc --devdoc --add-std --optimize -o /tmp/solc067035811",
      compilerVersion: "0.3.4",
      developerDoc: {
        methods: {}
      },
      language: "Solidity",
      languageVersion: "0.3.4",
      source: "contract Ceil { function ceil(uint a, uint m) constant returns (uint ) { return ((a + m - 1) / m) * m; }}",
      userDoc: {
        methods: {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you can reproduce the results above, your compiler installation is working correctly.

(The code is from [What is the cheapest way to roundup() or ceil() to multiple of 1000?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5836/what-is-the-cheapest-way-to-roundup-or-ceil-to-multiple-of-1000)).

Also, I'm getting the same results are you are when compiling an empty string:

```
> eth.compile.solidity("")
solc: empty source string
    at web3.js:3119:20
    at web3.js:6023:15
    at web3.js:4995:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

---

**EDIT 15/06/2016 - Responding to `@Matthias`**

Q: When you say the empty getCompilers result is normal, what does that mean exactly? What makes this function return something or not?

A: I don't know what the `[]` result from `eth.getCompilers()` exactly means, but when I run the following commands on my `geth console` screen, the results returned are what I see, and I have no problems compiling Solidity code from within `geth`. I'm just trying to eliminate the different points of error.

Here is what I see:

```
geth console
...
> eth.getCompilers()
I0615 01:17:48.956307 common/compiler/solidity.go:114] solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.3.4-0/RelWithDebInfo-Linux/g++/Interpreter

path: /usr/bin/solc
[]
> eth.getCompilers()
[]
```

The first run of `getCompilers()` produces some results from `solc`. From the command line, if I run `solc --version` I get the version information as well.

```
user@Kumquat:~/TestSolc$ solc --version
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.3.4-0/RelWithDebInfo-Linux/g++/Interpreter
```

If you can see similar information to what I am getting, you Solidity compiler is accessible from `geth`.

Here is one extra test you can try if you have a problem compiling Solidity source from within `geth`.

I've saved the following code into Ceil.sol:

```
contract Ceil {
    function ceil(uint a, uint m) constant returns (uint ) {
        return ((a + m - 1) / m) * m;
    }

    // To measure gas
    function ceil1(uint a, uint m) returns (uint ) {
        return ((a + m - 1) / m) * m;
    }
}
```

I'm now compiling outside `geth` using the command line parameters in the `ceilCompiled` results above:

```
user@Kumquat:~/TestSolc$ solc --bin --abi --userdoc --devdoc --add-std --optimize -o /tmp/solc067035811 Ceil.sol
```

Here is the contents of my /tmp/solc067035811 directory:

```
user@Kumquat:~/TestSolc$ ls -al /tmp/solc067035811/
total 24
drwxrwxr-x  2 bok  bok  4096 Jun 15 01:21 .
drwxrwxrwt 12 root root 4096 Jun 15 01:22 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 bok  bok   328 Jun 15 01:21 Ceil.abi
-rw-rw-r--  1 bok  bok   156 Jun 15 01:21 Ceil.bin
-rw-rw-r--  1 bok  bok    22 Jun 15 01:21 Ceil.docdev
-rw-rw-r--  1 bok  bok    22 Jun 15 01:21 Ceil.docuser
```

And here is the content of the files in the /tmp/solc067035811 directory:

```
user@Kumquat:~/TestSolc$ cat /tmp/solc067035811/Ceil.abi 
[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"a","type":"uint256"},
{"name":"m","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ceil1","outputs":
[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},
{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"a","type":"uint256"},
{"name":"m","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ceil","outputs":
[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"}]
user@Kumquat:~/TestSolc$ cat /tmp/solc067035811/Ceil.bin
6060604052603e8060106000396000f3606060405260e060020a600035046314bdae22811460245780638587be6e146024575b005b602435600435810160001901819004026060908152602090f3    user@Kumquat:~/TestSolc$ cat /tmp/solc067035811/Ceil.docdev 
{
   "methods" : {}
}
user@Kumquat:~/TestSolc$ cat /tmp/solc067035811/Ceil.docuser 
{
   "methods" : {}
}
```

If you can reproduce similar results running `solc` from your command line, the problem is most likely not in your Solidity compiler. You will have to keep searching for the cause.

Comment: Thank you @BokkyPooBah. The compiler was working fine. I just wanted to know whether eth,getCompilers() result was different only for me.

Comment: No worries. There was a segmentation fault problem with `solc` in another [question](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4102/link-solc-with-geth-problem), so I was curious enough to check your question out.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue as @varm. `solc` compiles your code snippet just fine on the cli (I'm getting the same binary string back), but as soon as I load up geth and try to compile via `eth.compile.solidity`, I get `solc: exit status 1; Unknown exception during compilation.` When you say the empty getCompilers result is normal, what does that mean exactly? What makes this function return something or not?

Comment: @Matthias, I've added some further information to help you try to solve your `solc` issue. Some possibilities: `solc` cannot create the temp subdirectory; `solc` cannot compile correctly with some of the command line parameters `--bin --abi --userdoc --devdoc --add-std --optimize -o /tmp/solc067035811`.

Comment: Thanks @BokkyPooBah -- I ran it with all these switches, and it works fine on the command line. I'm seeing all the same output and files created. Yet, I still cannot execute the compiler from within geth.

Comment: Do you have more than one `solc` executable installed on your system? You can use the command `find / -name 'solc'` in Linux or OS/X.