# Solc --version: command not found

Tags: solidity, nodejs, solc

I'm trying to use solc with no success.

I download solc with `npm install solc` but when I run `solc --version` the console output is:

```
command not found.
```

If I list packages `npm list` I'm able to see `solc@0.3.5`.

What's wrong?

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5840/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add solc to PATH. Type **which solc** to get the location where the solidity compiler is installed and add this to PATH. If you just want to check the version, navigate to the location where solidity is installed and then type in the command **solc --version**.

Comment: no output with **which solc**

I try also **npm install -g solc**

Comment: What result did you get for the **which solc** command?

Comment: nothing 

pippo-MacBook-Pro:~ pippo$ which solc 
pippo-MacBook-Pro:~ pippo$

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Contract-Tutorial#install-solc-on-mac-osx) and check if it works.

Comment: Now it seems to be ok. I download cpp-ethereum end in **geth console** set for **admin.setSolc()** the output of **which solc**.

So, solc always require cpp-ethereum, is not stand-alone?

Comment: Solidity doesn't require an ethereum client. A stand-alone version can be installed to develop and test smart contracts. But it is a built-in feature in the official Ethereum clients. Check [this](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-solidity.html) for more details.

Comment: Ok, but with **npm install solc**  ** --version** doesn't output nothing, **which solc** too, why? Tks for response

Comment: This is not a good answer. It doesn't address why `npm install solc` doesn't install a global `solc` tool, or how to install a compiler instead.

Answer (score 19):

If you have installed through `npm install -g solc`

[Here](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js#usage-on-the-command-line)'s how you use it. `solcjs --version`

Comment: doesn't say what's wrong, which is that without -g the command is not installed in the user's path.  The other solution is for the user to update their path.  This is really an npm issue...

Comment: Kind of annoying... Can I have my 15 minutes back? Surely you install `solc` and then run `solcjs`... Please.

Answer (score 3):

install solc compiler using

> npm install -g solc

it install compiler in global scope and use from any location.

To check version of installed compiler

> solcjs --version

is return something like "0.4.23+commit.124ca40d.Emscripten.clang"

more details are available [here](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js#usage-on-the-command-line).

Answer (score 2):

`npm install solc` currently does not install a globally available compiler. The `solc` npm package are just Javascript bindings to use in a Javascript module.

After struggling with this myself for some time, there currently seems to be no convenient way to install a standalone Solidity compiler, at least on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @graup, I've reinstalled solc from my contracts directory of each new contract project, which has worked for me:

```
cd contracts
npm install solc
npm install ethereumjs-testrpc web3@0.20.1

node

Web3 = require('web3')
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

code = fs.readFileSync('MyContrat.sol').toString()
solc = require('solc')
compileCode = solc.compile(code)
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm i solc@version`

By using this command you can do the installation of your required version solidity.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
solcjs --version
```

And even when compiling do solcjs.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue after installing globally, but `npx solc --version` fetched the version

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/83267)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can add to path if you have installed via python3 using pip3!

export PATH=$PATH:/Users/nolanjacobson/Library/Python/3.8/bin