# Solidity compiler

Tags: go-ethereum, compilation

I've been having issues trying to get a solidity compiler in both my windows and linux clients.
I've tried a few times - following instructions from answers from this community (some links are dead), repeating installations of geth with full dev options, you name it.

In the end of the day, when I run **eth.getCompilers()** it comes out null...

Ideally, I would be able to install on a linux server which is only connected to an intranet (I have geth running there, installed manually).  If that is not possible, I'll be glad if I can find a solc.exe that actually works, so I can run contracts trough the CLI.

Thanks for any help,
MB

Comment: It used to be the case that empty output from `eth.getCompilers()` was a red herring, and that it probably _was_ actually installed. Have you tried ignoring this, and attempted to compile anything? (See this thread for a similar discussion: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/5841/52)

Comment: Yes. I've tried compiling some small contracts with little success. I've also tried adding a new system variable for path, but there was just no solc.exe (I'm speaking only of the windows client... baby steps :P)  to direct it to...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have solidity compiler installed then you can try following:

- Get the path to the client using: `which solc` (for linux)
- Set path in geth console using: `admin.setSolc("path/to/solc")`

Comment: I got this error "TypeError: 'setSolc' is not a function"